# How to change navbar hover color on bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to change my navbar hover color to something else.
I managed to change navbar text color on my own, but I couldn't find the correct one to change in inspect element for hover color.

Then I looked it up on stackoverflow for previous asnwers but they didn't work for my code. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Basic template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  

    <style type="text/css">
      
      
    html,
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}





    </style>


    

  </head>
  <body>

<nav class="navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #0275D8;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>





<footer class="footer fixed-bottom text-center">
        <span class="text">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
    </footer>
</div>





    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use .navbar .navbar-nav li a:hover{color: red;}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">


    html,
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #ccc !important;
}
}
</style>
```

and html :

```
<nav class="navbar-expand-sm navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #0275D8;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: happy to help.. if it worked please mark it as answer

Comment: Sure. I have to wait few minutes to do that.

Comment: Was looking for hover background color, your answer helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap has default color for < a> tag. So by using !important you over write the color